# BindingSource.Current me devuelve siempre null

Tags: c#, .net, formularios, windows

Siendo que estamos en epoca de vacaciones vengo atrasado con la PP de la carrera, en este caso necesito seleccionar una celda de un datagridview y que con el bindingsource.current me devuelva algo diferente a null pero eso no pasa.
Este es todo el codigo del frm
el codigo esta basado en la programacion en capas que nos dieron en una materia,
ademas de todo esto esta escrito en los pdf pero no anda

```
public partial class Cliente : Form
{
    List<ClienteModel> clienteList = new List<ClienteModel>();
    public Cliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BuscarCliente();
    }

    private void reFreshGrid()
    {
        dtgEmpledos.DataSource = clienteList;
        dtgEmpledos.Refresh();
    }

    private void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clienteBindingSource.Current == null) 
            return; //aca hay un error y no me abre el form
        RegistrarCliente frm = new RegistrarCliente();
        frm.modo = EnumModoForm.Consulta;
        frm._clienteModel = (ClienteModel)clienteBindingSource.Current;
        frm.ShowDialog();
        reFreshGrid();
    }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de enlazar la lista de clientes al **DataGridView** enlazala al **BindingSource**, y entonces enlazarias el **DataGridView** a este **BindingSource**:

```
clienteBindingSource.DataSource = clienteList;
dtgEmpleados.DataSource = clienteBindingSource;
```

Tú error está en que el **BindingSource** no está enlazado a nada.

Comment: donde deberia poner eso? me perdi completamente, te dejo el link del github por si ayuda https://github.com/gamex99/SurFe/tree/main/SurFe_03-01-2024

Comment: Por lo que veo de tu código debe ir en el método reFreshGrid

Comment: me da el error de Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS0103 El nombre 'dtgEmpleados' no existe en el contexto actual, es la siguiente linea:   dtgEmpleados.DataSource = clienteBindingSource;

Comment: Pq tú tienes como nombre dtgEmpledos no dtgEmpleados, revisa bien que el error es más que obvio, fijate bien en lo que haces

Comment: Muchas gracias! voy a mirar mejor